# Why is casting failing when I am using ISNUMERIC()?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, casting

```
SELECT CAST([Revenue Size (M)] AS float)
FROM Raw_Data A
WHERE ISNUMERIC([Revenue Size (M)]) = 1
```

I get an error:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to float

Revenue Size (M) Samples:
7371
,7372
,4899
,59.5
,1.4
,2
,3400

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Please provide some data samples of [Revenue Size (M)].

Comment: it is for mysql and I have included sample data

Comment: your sample should be work. I think [Revenue Size (M)] contain some data with signs such as `$`,`-`,`+`,`,`,etc. Since `Select ISNUMERIC(N'$67')` is equal to 1, but you cannot convert it to float `Select CAST(N'$67' AS float)`

Comment: @Yash you are mistaken; mysql has no ISNUMERIC and doesn't allow quoting column names with `[]`.  tagging this sql-server

Comment: My apologies, this is for T-SQL. Also, thanks GGG, yes, data had some characters. Cleaning them worked. Thanks guys.

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` answers a question no sane developer would want to ask - "can this string be converted to *at least one* of the numeric datatypes, I don't care which one(s) it actually works for?"

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple examples where `isnumeric()` returns `1` but the value cannot be converted to a floating point number.  Four examples are:

- `'.'`
- `'-'`
- `'-.'`
- `'$1'`

You can see this in [this SQL Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=446e6296283eaf4c007fd7067c28040d).

The better course of action is to use `try_cast()`:

```
SELECT TRY_CAST([Revenue Size (M)] AS float)
FROM Raw_Data A
WHERE TRY_CAST([Revenue Size (M)] AS float) IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Gordon is correct +1

However, I tend to use MONEY when reasonable ... It seems to be a little more forgiving.

**Example**

```
Select AsMoney = try_convert(money,'$5,125')
      ,AsFloat = try_convert(float,'$5,125')
      ,AsInt   = try_convert(int,'$5,125')
      ,AsDec   = try_convert(decimal(10,2),'$5,125')
```

**Results**

```
AsMoney     AsFloat     AsInt       AsDec
5125.00     NULL        NULL        NULL
```

Comment: @Charlieface Only children use words like  "never" and "always".  My intent was to illustrate how money will convert while others fail.   Certainly don't think it worth a downvote.